# Very Simple Compile failing on Solaris 10

Tags: c++, solaris, solaris-10

I'm on a Solaris 10 box.
The compiler I'm using is: /opt/solstudio12.2/bin/CC

Compiling the file shown below (myTest2.C) fails.

```
% CC -I. -o myTest2 myTest2.C
"myTest2.C", line 30: Error: "{" expected instead of "myFunc".
"myTest2.C", line 33: Error: "{" expected instead of "myFunc".
2 Error(s) detected.
```

1. Why is it an error to call myFunc() while declaring a variable?
2. Is it because it is not within any function?
3. How to get around it?

FYI, I'm writing a string obfuscater that goes through lines of C++ code and replaces instances of a quoted string (Example: "myString") with a function call (Example: scrambleString("myString")). myFunc in this example is analogous to scrambleString

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



using namespace std;


char* myFunc(string inString)
{
    char outString[1024];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= inString.size()-1; i++)
        outString[i] = inString[i];
    outString[i+1] = '\0';
    return outString;
}



// This Works:
static char myVariable1 [ ] = "MyString1" ;

// This Breaks:
static char myVariable2 [ ] = myFunc("MyString2") ; // Line #30

// This Breaks:
char myVariable5 [1024] = myFunc("MyString3"); // Line
#33





int main()
{
    // This Works:
    string Z = myFunc("Gdkkn Vnqkc");
    cout << "Z = " << Z << endl << endl;    
}
```

Comment: What's the point in replacing "MyString" with `scramble("MyString")`?  The string literal is still in your code, unscrambled!

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear/incomplete in making that statement. I should have said the following: 

FYI, I'm writing a string obfuscater that goes through lines of C++ code and replaces instances of a quoted string (Example: "myString") with a function call (Example: descrambleString("ut5ml@de")). myFunc in this example is analogous to descrambleString and "ut5ml@de" is the scrambled version of "myString". descrambleString() will convert it back to the original at run time.


I didn't think anyone would be interested in those details or they were relevant. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not safe because your're returning stack contents, but apart from that you're returning a "char *".. Your code will *compile* (but still be unsafe since you're returning a pointer to contents on the stack) if you change the signature to:

```
static char *myVariable = myFunc("foo");
```

That being said.. Why not return a string object instead of using char*?

Comment: +1 for pointing out undefined behaviour problem and suggesting using string instead

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
// This Works:
static char myVariable1 [ ] = "MyString1" ;
```

works because a `char`-based literal string is an array of `char`. So you're initializing an array with an array.

The next few lines,

```
// This Breaks:
static char myVariable2 [ ] = myFunc("MyString2") ; // Line #30
```

don't work, because you're initializing an array of `char` with a `char*` pointer. An array must be initialized with an array. The curly braces notation is common, and that's what your compiler is complaining that it expects instead of a function call.

If what you want is to have some global string variables initialized by function calls, then consider using `std::string` and/or singleton functions. For example,

```
static std::string& myVariable2()
{
    static std::string theString = myFunc( "MyString2" );
    return theString;  // Return a reference to the string instance.
}
```

However, this is a technical solution to bad design, so I'm only recommending it as a purely technical solution to the current problem.

Instead, try to avoid global variables.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

1.Your function

```
char* myFunc(string inString)
{
    char outString[1024];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= inString.size()-1; i++)
        outString[i] = inString[i];
    outString[i+1] = '\0';
    return outString;
}
```

has a bug:
You are returning the pointer to a local variable. after the function returns the cariable outString will go out of scope. no matter even if you declare this as a std::string, you will get into trouble.

2.`static char myVariable2 [ ] = myFunc("MyString2") ; // Line #30`

Here the size of `myVariable2` is not known at compile time, so this will break

3.`char myVariable5 [1024] = myFunc("MyString3");`

This gives the error message as:

```
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer,
```

I think the error message says it all in this case.
The error message that you are getting  `"Error: "{" expected instead of "myFunc". "` is just another way of saying the same thing.

4.You are declaring global variables which is 'generally' not a good idea